# schedule monthly incidents reports in BMC remedy 8.1

Tags: automation, report, remedy, itil

i need to schedule monthly incidents reports in BMC remedy 8.1. the report needs to be distributed to certain recipients, for every month. Can this be achieved in remedy? If not what are the other ways?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AR System Report Console to schedule reports.  With the report selected that you want to automate, click on the calendar icon at the top right.

[image]

In the next window that appears, click on the "New" button at the top right.

[image]

From here, a window will appear that will allow you to schedule a recurring report on a daily, weekly, or monthly basis.  You can also specify email addresses to send it to and a preferred format (Excel, PDF, etc).